# React.js controlled select option (drop-down) select the changed value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code but when i change the value from drop-down the drop-down sticks to `Select the status` Rather changing it to the selected value i.e

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    status: "",
    priority: "",
    start_date: new Date(),
    due_date: new Date(),
    progress: 0,
    user_id: null,
  });

const task_statuses = ["active", "pending", "inactive", "completed"];

  const setData = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
    <select onChange={setData} name="status">
      <option value=""> Select Task Status </option>
        {task_statuses.map((status) => {
          return (
            <option key={shortid.generate()} value={status}>
              {capitalizeFirstLetter(status)}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
```

I would like it to change it to selected option, can't do it please help

Please Help

Comment: Have you looked at the example from the docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not setting value prop of select tag

Add value prop to **value={formData.priority}**

`<select onChange={setData} value={formData.priority} name="status">`

Thanks